# How do dynamically handle onmousemove inside object constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've got this set up:

```
<html>
...
<section id="main" onmousemove="view.updateLocation(event.clientX, event.clientY)">
    ...
</section>
<script>
    var view = new PageObj();
    view.show();
</script>
...
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

With an event inside `main.js` called `updateLocation(x, y)`, but I want to move the `onmousemove` to be handled by JavaScript entirely. How do I define a handler inside the `PageObj()` constructor to replace the `onmousemove="..."` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
function PageObj() {
    var section = document.getElementById("main");
    addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
        //mousemove stuff
    });
}
```